# get back the default Navigation bar after making it Transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, uinavigationbar

i'm making my navigation bar transparent like this :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    //UIImageNamed:@"transparent.png"
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    ////UIImageNamed:@"transparent.png"
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}
```

but its affecting the other view controller's Navigation bar too so for that i want to make it back as default when the current view disappears , how can i do that ?? 
i know that i have to do it in `ViewDidDisappear` but no idea what to do there

any guidance  will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i ended up with this , on my other viewController where i wanna show my navigationBar

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundImageForBarMetrics(.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .None
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(.None, forBarMetrics: .Default)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do reverse back to your viewController color in viewWillDisAppear() method.

override func viewWillDisAppear(animated: Bool) {

self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.WhiteColor()

}

hope this will be helpful to you

Comment: well thanks a lot for responding , yeah i  tried this but no luck bro @Bhaskar